# How to keep UITableView scroll smooth when "reloadData" finished then scroll to bottom frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I build a IM Message List use `UITableView` to display it。

when receive a new message, i do the 2 step as below:

1. `UITableView reloadData`
2. after step 1 done, scroll to bottom. I use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` with animate

but when receive message very frequently then it will frequently call step 1 & 2, so the `UITableView` look flash in this situation.

I hope one set of step 1 & 2 finished，can only be do the next set step 1 & 2 but i have no idea about this.

pls help.thx

Comment: you should not reload, instead u need to insert cell

Comment: U mean, reloadData change to insertRowsAtIndexPaths then scrollToRowAtIndexPath ? @Rathish

Comment: Yes... U can see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading tableView each time you receives new message, simply insert new message in tableDataArr and insert new row in tableView. Please check following code for the same

```
tableDataArr.append("New Message")
tableView.beginUpdates()
let indexpath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(row: tableDataArr.count-1, section: 0)
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexpath as IndexPath], with: .bottom)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Once new row get inserted in tableView scroll tableView to bottom cell with following code

`tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexpath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)`

If you don't want animation then set animated to false.
It will resolved your problem.

Comment: Thanks your answer, `scrollToRow` animation is need, it seems look find, but why it change to `insertRows` it will fine?